# Formatting a powershell table, removing entries

Tags: string, powershell, format

I'm new to powershell and I've run into a seemingly simple problem I just can't find the solution to.  I'm writing a script that pulls the serial number off of the current computer, it then queries a database and performs functions on the computer based on what the database says to do for that particular serial number. Now here's the problem, when I use the following code

```
$currSerial = Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_BIOS" | select SerialNumber
```

I receive output in what I'm pretty sure is a table, so when I output $currSerial I get this:

```
SerialNumber                                                                                                                                                
------------                                                                                                                                                
AGR0Agh99481028
```

All I want is to save the text "AGR0Agh99481028" to a string so that I can query the server with that number. right now my query is looking like this:

```
$Query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE serial = '$currSerial'"
```

output parses to this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE serial = '@{SerialNumber=D1N0AS249667028     }'
```

I read about the get-item cmd and it seems like I'd already have to know what the serial was to search for it. Is there some cmdlet that I can use to make this easier?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a flag:

`$currSerial = Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_BIOS" | select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber`

`-ExpandProperty` will turn it in to a plain-old string.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `select` is an *object* with just the specified properties. To get the serial number *string* change

```
Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_BIOS" | select SerialNumber
```

into

```
(Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_BIOS" | select SerialNumber).SerialNumber
```

Comment: A little OT, but it seems this is the 2nd time I've used `-ExpandProperty` inappropriately. What exactly is it used for?

Comment: I wouldn't consider `select -Expand SerialNumber` inappropriate. It's just a different way to get the same result.

Comment: @r.tanner.f your use of `-ExpandProperty` was appropriate. There's more than one way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Or even shorter

```
$currSerial = (Get-WMIObject -Class "Win32_BIOS").SerialNumber
```